# Should I implement CSV reader methods as static for better Testing in Java?

Tags: java, csv, unit-testing, integration-testing, opencsv

I am trying to implement an Helper class using OpenCSV and I am thinking to define the related methods as static like this:

```
public class CsvHelper {

    private enum Headers {
        ID,
        NAME,
        EMAIL,
        COUNTRY
    }

    public static List<EmployeeRequest> csvToEmployees(InputStream is) throws IllegalAccessException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
             CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader,
                     CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim())) {

            List<EmployeeRequest> employees = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterable<CSVRecord> records = parser.getRecords();

            for (CSVRecord rec : records) {
                EmployeeRequest employee = new EmployeeRequest(
                        Long.parseLong(rec.get(Headers.ID)),
                        rec.get(Headers.NAME),
                        rec.get(Headers.EMAIL),
                        rec.get(Headers.COUNTRY)
                );
                employees.add(employee);
            }
            return employees;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException("Failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure if I should define csvToEmployees method without static in a service class for proper testing. So:

**1.** Should I define `csvToEmployees` method in this Helper class as static? Or should I define it in y service as the other service methods (without static)?

**2.** Can I write Unit and Integration test for reading data from CSV file? Or should I write only Integration test for that?

Comment: This can be good as first attempt, but as soon as you will need to handle more CSV, you will need to add a lot of code in this CsvHelper class. So I think you should create a more Generic method using Java Generics. You will benefit from that in the future.

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan Thanks a lot Paul, I generated a generic classes by following **Template Method Design Pattern**. But, your reply actually is not cover my 2 questions. So, may I get your opinions for these 2 questions above?

Comment: I don't understand how unittesting can benefit from making the method `static`. In contrast it will make the code using your utility *harder* to test since you cannot simply pass a test dummy of `CsvHelper` to isolate the other code from it.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I mean it makes unit testing harder and that is why I am asking the question. Then, do you mean that I should not make the method static? And inject the helper class or service class where I keep CSV method to my controller?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle What about answering my 2 questions?

Comment: *" Then, do you mean that I should not make the method static?"* **--** Yes. **/** *"And inject the helper class or service class where I keep CSV method to my controller?"* **--** Yes. **/** *"1. Should I define csvToEmployees method in this Helper class as static?"* **--** No. **/** *"Or should I write only Integration test for that?"* **--** No. UnitTest have a different scope and purpose then integration tests. You cannot exchange one test type for the other.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle  Perfect explanations, thanks a lot for detailed and clear replies :)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle By the way, if do you have an idea, may I get your valuable comments for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74544030/should-i-prefer-filereader-to-bufferedreader-while-reading-csv/74544248#74544248

Comment: I agree with the answer of @Chaosfire.