# Should I prefer FileReader to BufferedReader while reading CSV?

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, filereader, opencsv

In a Spring Boot app, I am reading csv file data using OpenCSV and it is possible to use FileReader to BufferedReader with it. However, when I compare both of them, I have a dilemma for the following point:

> BufferedReader is faster than FileReader, but it uses much more memory.

As I am reading multiple data file (having hundreds of thousands records) in the same method (first I read data from one csv and then use the retrieved id fields to read the second csv), I think I shouldn't use `BufferedReader` for less memory usage. But I am really not sure what is the most proper way.

So, in this situation, Should I prefer FileReader to BufferedReader?

Comment: hi, the answer will mainly depends on which resource is your limitation : disk access ? ram ? time ? File reader will be a little more efficient on ram usage thats right but if your limitation is on disk or time  BufferedRead will optimize the parallele file reading  by making longer read on the same disk zone that will reduce system resource access cost and this is expensive in java, by the way if you now the size of your files you can custom buffered reader by passing a size to its constructor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, **depends** on your constraints. If performance is an issue, allocate more resources and go for the faster solution. If memory is an issue, do the reverse.

With `BufferedReader` you can also use the reader and int [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader-java.io.Reader-int-) to set buffer size, which suits your needs.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(Reader, bufferSize);
```

Another general rule of thumb, don't do premature optimizations, be it memory or performance. Strive for clean code, if a problem arises, use a profiler to identify the bottlenecks and then deal with them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Actually it is not premature optimization as I will not have to update the project (it is an assignment actually :) So, my priority is actually memory, but I am not sure when I use `bufferSize`, what if the read records overflow the allocated size? For reading a CSV with 500.000 records, should I use `FileReader`? On the other hand, OpenCSV uses `FileReader` in all of its examples. But I am not sure if that is the most proper way. Any clarification pls?

Comment: @gonzales `bufferSize` is the size of the buffer during reading, basically the size of the chunk being read from the source at once. Bigger buffer means faster reading and more memory used during reading, smaller buffer means slower reading and lower memory used. You don't need to worry about it overflowing, BufferedReader takes care of this.

Comment: Also 500k records is not a small number, depending on constraints and what you need to do with them, you may need to work with them on batches. Read `n` records, process them, and move on to the next `n` records. The same rules applies to this - bigger `n` means faster processing, but more memory will be needed.

Comment: Hmmm, very good information especially regarding to buffer size. In this situation >>>

Comment: **1)** what about using  FileReader instead of BufferedReader?

Comment: **2)** What is the bufferSize value that I should use for this scenario when I use `BufferedReader`?

Comment: @gonzales 1) Personally i have never needed to use FIleReader, instead of BufferedReader, when dealing with text files. 2) Can't say, i don't know the exact constraints. You can always try with the default size and decrease it later if it's too much.

Comment: Thanks amigo, voted up and marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know the difference in size lies simply in the buffer size, which by default is 8k or 16k, so the difference is memory isn't huge; the most important thing is you remember to free the resources when you don' use them anymore, calling close(), also remember to do it incase of Exceptions

Comment: The safest way to remember to close the resources is to just use try-with-resources every time. That way you can't "forget" to close on exceptions.

Comment: By the way I tried, but cannot voted up as I have not enough reputation :( Any vote up for the question pls?

Comment: @JoachimSauer By the way, when I use `try-with-resources`, should I only add the variables that should be closed in the try block as `try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
  CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());
}` Is that true? Or should I also keep `CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());` in the `try()` ?

Comment: Thanks amigo, voted up. Any idea about my previous comment?

Comment: I think you must put also the sceond part in the try block, because it uses reader  that is defined in the first instruction, otherwise the BufferedReader would be closed too early